# MKLocalSearchCompleter - Ignores region

Tags: swift, mapkit, mklocalsearch

I'm trying to make an address search using the `MKLocalSearchCompleter`. I've provided it with a region(Australia) but the provided region is completely ignored, I still get results from around the world.

```
...

private var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()

....

init {
    searchCompleter.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -25.2744, longitude: 133.7751), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 40, longitudeDelta: 40)) // Australia
    searchCompleter.resultTypes = [.address]
    searchCompleter.delegate = self

    searchCompleter.queryFragment = "Wycombe Road"
}

extension MapSearchCompleter: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        print("+++ \(completer.results)")
    }
}
```

If I try to print the region in the delegate method `completerDidUpdateResults`, I get the region back.

> +++ MKCoordinateRegion(center: __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -25.2744, longitude: 133.7751), span: __C.MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 40.0, longitudeDelta: 40.0))

Any idea how to make it work? Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I can just filter out addresses manually, but I don't think that the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way `

```
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchTxt
        request.region = mkMapView.region
        // Fetch
        MKLocalSearch(request: request).start { (response, _) in
            guard let result = response else { return }
            self.place = result.mapItems.compactMap({ (item) -> Place? in
                return Place(placemark: item.placemark)
            })
        }
```